# Primefaces dialog not binding values to bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have `h:form` in PrimeFaces `p:dialog`. All other components works fine, even the `p:selectOneMenu`, but **value of `p:inputText` is not bound to bean and gives null.**

```
<p:dialog header="Delivery Schedule" id="deleditdlg" widgetVar="deleddlg1" showEffect="clip"
                hideEffect="clip" styleClass="dialogwidth"
                    modal="true" appendTo="@(body)" closable="true" width="500">
                    <h:form id="saveform">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold;"
                                        value="Timing: "></h:outputLabel>
                                <br/>
                                    <p:inputText value="#{deliveryScheduleBean.deliverySchedule.vehTiming}"></p:inputText>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold;"
                                        value="Status: "></h:outputLabel>
                                <br/>
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{deliveryScheduleBean.deliverySchedule.vehStatus}">
                                       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Active" itemValue="0"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inactive" itemValue="1"></f:selectItem>

                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <br />
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
                                    <p:commandButton class="btn btn-success" process="saveform"
                                        action="#{deliveryScheduleBean.updateSchedule}" value="Save"></p:commandButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </h:form>
                </p:dialog>
```

Comment: So it works when you remove the dialog?

Comment: or when you remove the `<div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">` or `<div class="row">` etc...[mcve].... please...

Comment: What type is the vehTiming field, Date? Could you post at last this bean code and maybe all your page code?